# Ubuntu Refresh fwupd service failure

Tags: ubuntu, server-error

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server running on Amazon Lightsail. Within the last 4 weeks, the server keeps going offline for a 15-20 min at a time, and then comes back online. Sometimes it happens every 4-5 hours, sometimes 1-2 times a day.

I checked the server logs (in syslog) and found this around the same time as the incidents:

```
systemd[1]: Starting Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd...
systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
CRON[94256]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

I would appreciate some help in debugging/solving this issue.